# AutoMapper mapping objects in source child list to existing objects in destination child entity collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have the following situation:

```
public class Parent : EntityObject
{
    EntityCollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child : EntityObject
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Value1 { get; set; }
    string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class ParentViewModel
{
    List<ChildViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Value1 { get; set; }
    string Value2 { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<ParentViewModel, Parent>();

Mapper.CreateMap<ChildViewModel, Child>();
```

Is it possible to get AutoMapper to:

- Map objects in the `ParentViewModel.Children` list to objects in the `Parent.Children` EntityCollection with matching Ids.
- Create new objects in `Parent.Children` for objects in `ParentViewModel.Children` where an object with the id from source is not found in the destination list.
- Remove objects from `Parent.Children` where the destination id does not exist in the source list.

Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Did you end up figuring out how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid automapper is not meant to be used for mapping to a populated object, it will erase the Parent.Children wen you invoke Map().
You have several approaches here:

- Create the condition to execute the map on children youself:

  ```
   foreach (var childviewmodel in parentviewmodel.Children)
   {
       if (!parent.Children.Select(c => c.Id).Contains(childviewmodel.Id))
       {
           parent.Children.Add(Mapper.Map<Child>(childviewmodel));
       }
   }
  ```

Add more `if()`s for other behaviour

- Create an IMappingAction and hook it in the BeforeMap method:

  ```
   class PreventOverridingOnSameIds : IMappingAction<ParentViewModel, Parent>
   {
       public void Process (ParentViewModel source, Parent destination)
       {
           var matching_ids = source.Children.Select(c => c.Id).Intersect(destination.Children.Select(d => d.Id));
           foreach (var id in matching_ids)
           {
               source.Children = source.Children.Where(c => c.Id != id).ToList();
           }
       }
   }
  ```

..and later on

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<ParentViewModel, Parent>()
        .BeforeMap<PreventOverridingOnSameIds>();
```

this way you let automapper do the job.

Comment: Thanks for this work around, very useful! However what did you mean by rethinking architecture, what would you suggest as an alternative? I was under the impression use of DTOs was good practise especially for managing things such as REST APIs.

Comment: It absolutely is, I don't remember what I meant with that. Edited it out since it doesn't really make much sense.